# Import a MutivariatePolynomials output into JuMP as a user defined function

Tags: julia, polynomials, nonlinear-optimization, julia-jump

I am trying import the output of a function from MultivariatePolynomials and use it into JuMp as a function. Below is the related code, which is part of a large system of NL equations.

```
using JuMP
using MultivariatePolynomials 
@polyvar k s θ_1k θ_2k θ_3k θ_4k θ_5k θ_6k θ_7k θ_8k θ_9k θ_10k θ_11k θ_12k θ_13k E ρ   
d=....    
j_11=subs(d,k=>q11(θ_1k,θ_2k,θ_3k,θ_4k,θ_5k,θ_6k,θ_7k,θ_8k,θ_9k),s=>f(s,ρ,E))
c_11=subs(j_11, k=>-0.7071067811865476,s=>0)

function v11(θ_1k,θ_2k,θ_3k,θ_4k,θ_5k,θ_6k,θ_7k,θ_8k,θ_9k,ρ,E)
    c_11
end

m=Model(solver=IpoptSolver())

JuMP.register(m, :v11, 27, v11, autodiff=true)

@NLconstraint(m,cons1, ((v11(θ_1k,θ_2k,θ_3k,θ_4k,θ_5k,θ_6k,θ_7k,θ_8k,θ_9k,θ_10k,θ_11k,θ_12k,θ_13k,ρ, E))*w_1+*β*(1-δ+...

solve(m)
status=solve(m)
```

I receive the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching parseNLExpr_runtime(::JuMP.Model, ::DynamicPolynomials.PolyVar{true}, ::Array{ReverseDiffSparse.NodeData,1}, ::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1})

Closest candidates are:
  parseNLExpr_runtime(::JuMP.Model, ::Number, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\JuMP\src\parsenlp.jl:196
  parseNLExpr_runtime(::JuMP.Model, ::JuMP.Variable, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\JuMP\src\parsenlp.jl:202
```

It seems the output `c_11` has not been transformed as a multivariate-function type as I tried by defining a function `v11`, but remained as a polynomial type. How can I solve the issue?
Please, I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Please have a look whether my edit has not distorted any meaning. And try to familiarize youself with the markup tools  and Markdown (there's a little help button on the top right) -- they are usually much easier to use than linewise formatting by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it was resolved on [discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/converting-multivariatepolynomials-output-as-a-function-to-be-used-in-jump/11262/7).